# In which case would MySQL's InnoDB's COMPACT row_format would be faster/better than REDUNDANT?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I saw many comparisons on Stackoverflow, DBA and Server Fault, but it's never actually clear when it comes to performance with specific situations, whether using `COMPACT` or `REDUNDANT` row format with InnoDB

Are there any cases in which some simple tables would have a definitive performance boost? For example in a simple relational table `user_roles` that would map a `users` table with a `roles` table, using two `integers` that will always make a row the same size on disk?

If that's not a good example, are there good examples that would make a clear difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COMPACT` format is slightly better with storing field lengths. `REDUNDANT` stores length for every field even if it's a fixed size INT. `COMPACT` however stores only lengths of variable length fields.

IMO that will contribute to performance difference so little that it doesn't make sense to bother with formats.

[image: REDUNDANT format]
[image: COMPACT format]

Comment: Thanks! that's reassuring !

Answer (score 2):

YMMV.

I'm pretty sure this is a case where there is no easy categorization of schemas into "this schema would be better (worse) using that row format".

You did not mention `DYNAMIC` or `COMPRESSED`, which were introduced in later versions.  Let me give my opinion on all 4 formats...

Better would be to see if your code takes advantage of any of the row formats.  The main difference has to do with the handling of `TEXT` (etc) columns.  `SELECT *` asks for all columns to be returned, but if you specify all but the text columns, the query will *probably* run a lot faster because the off-row columns don't need to be fetched.

Having the first 767 bytes of a column included in the main part of the row *may* provide some speedup.  But this depends on what you are doing that could use only the first part of the text, *and* whether there is an optimization to actually take advantage of the particular case.  Note:  "prefix indexes" (eg, `INDEX my_text(44)`) are useful *only in a few cases*.)

`COMPRESSED` is of dubious utility -- there is a lot of overhead involved in having both the compressed and uncompressed copies in the buffer_pool.  I have trouble imagining a situation where compressed is clearly better.  And the compression rate is typically only 2:1.  Ordinary text compression is 3:1.  If you have big text/blob strings, I think it is better to do client compression (to cut back on network bandwidth) of selected `TEXT` columns and store into `BLOBs`.

If you have a table with only two integers in it, there will be a lot of overhead.  See `SHOW TABLE STATUS`; it will probably say Avg_row_length of maybe 40 bytes.  And even more if that does not include a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Furthermore, due to various other things, it would be difficult to see much difference in "faster/better" unless the table has over, say, a million rows.

Bottom line:  Go with the default for your version.  Don't lose sleep over the decision.

For *performance* focus on indexes and formulation of queries.  For *space*, test your table and report back.  Be aware that "free space" comes in many flavors, most of which are *not* reported anywhere, so size number can change if you sneeze at the table.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanations friend!